# Project view in InteliJ like in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

There is able to see project in IntelliJ Idea like in Eclipse?
I mean that I want to see all projects (from wokspace) in one window in one tree.

How to do something like this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse's concept of a "workspace" corresponds to IntelliJ IDEA's concept of a "project". You should add all of your projects as modules to a single IntelliJ IDEA project.